# how to know user has clicked the call and email send in android

Tags: android

I have an app that allow to send email and phone another user. I would like to know how many people have really called and sent email to another users. However, when user click the button that in my app to call the people, and it will go to the standard android call page and same as the email. When it goes to another activity or even another app, I have no idea whether the user has click 'call/send' button or cancel button.

How do I know if the user has really clicked on the call button?

Comment: We get the resultCode on onActivityResult,through which we come to know that the button was clicked but we fail to get which was clicked.we get the same resultCode on different click events.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is possible, but have you tried to start Email and Call app with `startActivityForResult(yourIntent)` ? It may be the case that the Email and Call App will sent a Result back, indicating a cancel or success, which you can catch in `onActivityResult(...)`

Comment: the problem is , you dont know if the user click the call button or just click back button

Comment: I thought, If he click JUST back-button, the Result will be `Cancelled` ?!